# Finding a solution for $(2\sin y-2x)y'-y=0$ that goes through the point ($\frac{2}{\pi},\pi$).

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do I find a solution for the differential equation:
$(2\sin y-2x)y'-y=0$

that goes through the point ($\frac{2}{\pi},\pi$) by using the property of inverse function: $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}= \frac{1}{f(x,y)}$?
do I need to change every $y$ by $x$ and every $x$ by $y$?  I tried to do both but without success of finding a solution for the equation that goes through that specific point from the type $x(y)=$..., which means $y$ as a function of $x$.
any kind of help/directing would appreciated.

Comment: i have only found this here  $$x=\frac{c_1}{y(x)^2}+\frac{2 (\sin (y(x))-y(x) \cos (y(x)))}{y(x)^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2\sin y-2x}{y}=\frac{dx}{dy} $$
is solved by
$$ x(y) = \frac{1}{y^2}\left(C+2\sin y-2y\cos y\right) $$
hence if a solution goes through $\left(\frac{2}{\pi},\pi\right)$ we have $C=0$.